# Convert a vector in Lambert Conformal Conical Projection to Cartesian

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations, conformal-geometry, spherical-trigonometry, geodesy

I have wind vectors with 2 components $(u, v)$ that are in the Lambert Conformal Conical Projection. I want to compare the vectors with observations of the wind $(u_{obs}, v_{obs})$ that are created in a regular latitude and longitude grid (a locally Cartesian frame). Components in Lambert and latitude/longitude grid can't be compared directly as they are in different projections.

In the case of **points** I know how to go from Lambert to latitude/longitude and viceversa: the formulas are long but solvable. Here we have the equations: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertConformalConicProjection.html
These formulas transform points, but I don't know how to do it with **vectors**.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I self-anwser my question, in case it can helps someone. What we need is the Jacobian. Wikipedia provides details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

With the equations of transformations from latitude and longitude to Lambert space: $x=x(\phi, \lambda)$ and $y=y(\phi, \lambda)$ we compute the Jacobian:

$$J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    \partial_{\phi}x & \partial_{\lambda}x \\
    \partial_{\phi}y & \partial_{\lambda}y
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, for vectors like velocity:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    dx \\
    dy
 \end{pmatrix} = J \begin{pmatrix}d\phi \\ d\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

In case you want geographical coordinates $(X, Y)$, $dX = \cos\phi \;R d\lambda$, $dY = R d\phi$ you can apply a second Jacobian to go from latitude and longitude to geographical coordinates:

$$ J_1 = \frac{1}{R}\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    \frac{1}{\cos\phi} & 0
 \end{pmatrix} ; \begin{pmatrix}
    d\phi \\
    d\lambda
 \end{pmatrix} = J_1 \begin{pmatrix}dX \\ dY\end{pmatrix}$$

So, in the end:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    dx \\
    dy
 \end{pmatrix}_{Lambert} = JJ_1 \begin{pmatrix}dX \\ dY\end{pmatrix}_{Geographical}$$